# Sharethis button image

Tags: html, css, image, button

See http://www.tuxx.nl/internationaal/vliegafstanden/internationaal/. Now scroll down and you see a button bar and one button with `Doorsturen` on it. Now, it works fine in Chrome, Firefox, but in Internet Explorer 8 you can see an e-mail icon. I looked where it came from and I saw that Sharethis automatically puts an image inside the button. I tried to get rid of that, but that didn't work. How can I remove this image/icon?

Comment: Oh IE, will you ever make a web developer happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use firebug to see if it has classes and use css to hide it with `display:none;`

If it does not have any class/id you could try to catch it with css selector `img[src="/*YOUR IMAGE SRC*/"`

To better help you I need to see some code ;)